# How are memcached servers used to perform a DDoS attack?

Tags: ddos

If I understand it correctly memcached servers respond with a larger packet as response to a user request.

1. I spoof my address to `1.1.1.0` (memcached servers).
2. Now that I, masquerading as the memcached server address. I can send packets to `rival.com`
3. `rival.com` will turn down.

Comment: @schroeder I filtered out the confusion. rival.com is the target who will receive the load of the memcached servers ultimately, hope this helps.

Comment: I think you have this backwards. You can spoof the source of a request. So, you spoof rival.com's ip and connect to the memcached servers who respond to rival.